# MMDrawerController not working with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, mmdrawercontroller

Here is my podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'myApp' do
    pod 'PureLayout', '~> 2.0.6'
    pod 'MMDrawerController', '~> 0.5.7'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.2.0'
end
```

And here is my briding header:

```
#import <PureLayout/PureLayout.h>
#import <MMDrawerController/MMDrawerController.h>
#import <MMDrawerController/MMDrawerVisualState.h>
```

When I'm setting this variable, `var drawerController: MMDrawerController!`, I get this error:

```
Use of undeclared type 'MMDrawerController'
```

I've tried deleting all the pods and running `pod install`, clearing the `pod cache` and running `pod update`, however I still haven't had any luck. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

I must be doing something wrong with my bridge header, because I can completely remove these lines:

```
#import <MMDrawerController/MMDrawerController.h>
#import <MMDrawerController/MMDrawerVisualState.h>
```

And the program will run fine as long as I import `MMDrawerController` in the files that are using it. However, this doesn't work vice versa